# A pretty binary grid 

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Screenshot of the puzzle's grid.]

What will I be doing this weekend?

---

For convenience, I'm also providing the grid in text form:

> 0100X1000 0101X0101 0100X1111 0100X1101 0101X0011 0100X0110 0100X1001 0101X0010 0100X0101 0100X1001
>  0101X0000 0100X1111 0100X0010 0101X0000 0100X1111 0101X0011 0101X0000 0100X1011 0100X1011 0100X0001
>  0101X0011 0100X0101 0101X0000 0101X0100 0100X0101 0100X1101 0100X0010 0100X0101 0101X0010 0100X0110
>  0101X1001 0101X0100 0100X0001 0100X0101 0101X0111 0100X0100 0101X0100 0100X1001 0100X1111 0101X0100
>  0101X0111 0101X0111 0100X1110 0101X0011 0101X0010 0100X0001 0100X1001 0100X0101 0100X0010 0100X0101
>  0101X1000 0100X0101 0100X1000 0101X0000 0101X0100 0100X0001 0101X1001 0101X1010 0101X0011 0101X0010
>  0101X0011 0100X1100 0101X1000 0100X0111 0101X1001 0100X0101 0101X0100 0101X0101 0100X0110 0100X1110
>  0100X1011 0100X0110 0100X0100 0101X0010 0100X0101 0101X0001 0101X0010 0100X1001 0101X1000 0100X1111
>  0101X1001 0101X0100 0100X1000 0101X0001 0101X1010 0100X1000 0101X1000 0100X1110 0100X1111 0100X1111
>  0100X1100 0100X1000 0101X1010 0100X0100 0100X0110 0100X1111 0101X0101 0101X0010 0101X0100 0100X1110

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Step 1

> If we take the eight digit binary string provided by each square and convert to ASCII (this can be done by taking the text version of the puzzle and removing the Xs), we get the following 10x10 grid of letters
>
> ```
>  HUOMSFIREI
>  POBPOSPKKA
>  SEPTEMBERF
>  YTAEWDTIOT
>  WWNSRAIEBE
>  XEHPTAYZSR
>  SLXGYETUFN
>  KFDREQRIXO
>  YTHQZHXNOO
>  LHZDFOURTN
> ```

Step 2

> This looks like a wordsearch and it contains the words FIRE, SEPTEMBER, FOUR (all going across), SKY, TWELFTH and AFTERNOON (all going down) OPERATION, EASTERN (diagonally going down to the right). There may be more words but I think this has to do with
>  The Fortnite Season Seven **OPERATION: SKY FIRE** event which takes place at **FOUR** in the **AFTERNOON EASTERN** Time on **SEPTEMBER TWELFTH** (which lets us know what you'll be doing).